# Django if m2m field object is selected

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Trying to do some logic based on the selected m2m field objects

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)


class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    contact=models.ManyToManyField(Contact, blank=True)
    ...
```

So contact are Phone, SMS, Email, Skype etc. Now I need to check if Phone is selected in Item.contact so I'm try to do:

```
item = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
if 'Phone' in item.contact.all():
    #do some logic
```

But it doesn't work. In template `{{ item.contact.all }}` gives `[<Contact: Phone>,<Contact: SMS>, <Contact: Email>]` so how can I see is it Phone selected or not in view or template whatever.

Comment: Be wary that what you're trying to do just checks for the existence of a phone contact, but it doesn't tell you if a user has 'selected' it or not. Your current model setup makes it possible for an Item to have a Phone AND an Email AND a Skype contact. But doesn't force the selection of a primary or a single contact method.

Comment: Yes thank you. I do if any(item.contact.filter(name='Phone') or item.contact.filter(name='SMS')): then I place logic for display phone number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item.contact.all()` produces an iterable of `Contact` objects, so you need to check the `name` attribute of the `contact`.

If you need to check if the item has a phone contact, then you can use the following:

```
if any(contact for contact in item.contact.all() if contact.name == 'Phone'):
    # your logic here
```

Or, more simply:

```
if any(item.contact.filter(name='Phone')):
    # your logic
```

Actually, using [.exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) is probably the better method if you don't need to access the `contact` instance:

```
if item.contact.filter(name='Phone').exists():
    # your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change your class structure.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    selected = models.BooleanField(initial=True,blank=False,null=False)


class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    contact=models.ManyToManyField(Contact, blank=True)
    ...
```

To get the current contact thats True, you could try this (excuse my django its rusty)

```
item = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
preferred_contact = item.contact.get(selected__exact=True)
```